# What's the reason behind $e^{tx} \leq \frac{b-x}{b-a}e^{ta}+\frac{x-a}{b-a}e^{tb}$?

Tags: inequality, intuition

$e^{tx}$ is a convex function of $x$

Then, $\forall x\in [a,b]$

$e^{tx} \leq \frac{b-x}{b-a}e^{ta}+\frac{x-a}{b-a}e^{tb}$ holds.

Which is not same as convex definition $f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\leq tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)$.

An explanation of my inequality would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: 1) Replace $t$ in $f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\leq tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)$ by $u$. 2) Write $u = (b - x)/(b - a)$. What do you get?:)

Comment: It's the convex inequality, you just have to find the right values to give to $x_1$ and $x_2$. A great example of results that seem harder than a previously known theorem is the interpolation inequality, that follows by Holder's with some tricky substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the letter $t$ twice for two different things. Instead use $$f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2) \le \lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda) f(x_2).$$

Let $x_1 = a$, $x_2 = b$, and $\lambda = \dfrac{b-x}{b-a}$.

Comment: $x_1=at $ and $x_2=bt$?

Comment: The function was clearly (if implicitly) defined as $f(x) = e^{tx}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for a convex function

$$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)\le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y) $$

and in this case

- $x=at$
- $y=bt$
- $\lambda= \frac{b-x}{b-a}$